# firebase device grouping with android post http method

Tags: android, firebase, networking, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am current a student and i am learning firebase, android and ios and i am using firebase cloud messaging and i want to group the tokens and i got the solution but it said i have to have a post request by sending the json data along with some other data i.e,

```
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=API_KEY
project_id:SENDER_ID

{
   "operation": "create",
   "notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris",
   "registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

And it's link is: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group
Please Help me!

Comment: Hi Tushar. Sorry, what's the question exactly?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply my question was basically how to send a http post request with headers and body like above.

Comment: You could use [Postman or cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/8242/firebase-cloud-messaging#t=20170614125643248374)